# Should I ship the FastMM include file in my Delphi 6 application installation files?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, installation, fastmm

I use FastMM4 in my Delphi 6 applications.  Do I need to ship the include file (FastMM4Options.inc) with the installation files I create to install my app on a users PC? If so, should I put it in the same directory that I place the main EXE file?

I'm referring to the FastMM include file that controls the settings for FastMM at run-time.  Currently this file is in a directory that is accessible via the Library Path specified in my Delphi IDE Environment options, but I never considered to include it with my installation program(s).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`FastMM4Options.inc` is an include file; it's source code.  It doesn't affect anything at runtime; it affects how FastMM is configured at compile-time. So no, there's no need to ship it to anyone.